# Binary Tree - Finding the kth order of a node (smallest to largest)

Tags: java, binary-tree

what's a good way to find the kth order of a node in a binary tree?

This is what I have so far, nothing I seem to try works the way I thought it would.

The given method that his tester program calls is findByOrder(int k), Index of the smallest element is 0, index of the largest element is root.size() - 1. So k = 1 would return the second smallest element of the tree.

This is what I currently have which isn't working one bit, the starting method is findByOrder(int k), the other two were helper methods I tried to implement.

```
    public Node<T> findFirst(Node<T> r) {
    while(r.left != null) {
        if(r.left != null);
        r = r.left;
    }

    return r;
}

public Node<T> findOrder(Node<T> r, Node<T> last, int k) {
    if(r.left != null && r.right != null) {
        if(r.left != last || r.right != last) {
            findOrder(r.left, last, k);
;       }

        if(r.left == last) {
            if(r.right != null) {
                return r.right;
            } else {
                return r;
            }
        }
    }

    return r;
}

/**
 * Return the kth indexed element according to the Comparable sorted order of
 * the tree. The leftmost node has index 0 and the rightmost node has index
 * size() - 1.
 * 
 * @param k
 *            index
 * @return element, or null if k is out of range.
 */
public T findByOrder(int k) {
    int count = 0;
    Node<T> oNode = findFirst(root);

    if(k < 0 || k > (root.size() - 1)) return null;

    while(count != k) {
        count = count + 1;

        findOrder(root, oNode, k);
    }

    return oNode.data;
}
```

I apologize if it's sloppy. I looked up many different methods to achieve this, but with the binary tree I'm given by the professor, none of them seem to work properly.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how is a node of k-th order defined? (How k-th order is defined)

Comment: @ZhaoGang nooo, that makes things complicated ;) (Technically you are right though, after all this is homework)

Comment: @leonardkraemer I edited it with clarification of the kth order. But it's the node at the kth order, so at k = 1 would be the second lowest node ( I messed up the title, I just realized)

Comment: I guess he is looking for a in-order traversal algorithm

Comment: @ZhaoGang Yes! That's it, sorry I didn't know what it was called.

Comment: Different solution for different requirements. Will findingByOrder be called many times?

Comment: "k is the order that the node was placed in tree" is not a clarification, basically it means nothing, It is like saying a cat is a cat. "k = 1 would be the second lowest node" is a bit better, but not good as well, because trees can be imbalanced in various ways. Sorry if this sounds rude, it is not meant to be. Please give the exact definition as in your assignment and the tree implementation. Especially the put method is interesting.

Comment: If only once, in-order traverse the tree and use a counter to record the order,when the counter hits the k you know you can stop . If many times, in-order traverse the whole tree, store the index-node map into a hashmap for future usage.

Comment: @leonardkraemer How about this: Index of the smallest element is 0, index of the largest element is root.size() - 1. So k = 1 would return the second smallest element of the tree.

Comment: Much better, you resolved the ambiguities. (the problem was that order was not defined before, as there can be many orders.)

Comment: one simple but may not be very efficient way is to transform the tree into an array, do it recursively from left-most to right-most nodes. then you can get k-th node from the array.